# Frozen Windows 7 Login Screen (freezes after correct credentials)

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, login, credentials

Here is the scenario. I turn on the laptop, it loads, the login screen comes up. I enter the correct credentials and it says "Welcome" and the cursor turns into the loading symbol. However, shortly after, the symbol freezes, and I can't do anything but move the useless cursor around. If I wait around long enough (an hour~) it will send me back to the login screen.

Here is my work in progress:
I started my computer in safe mode. I login with the credentials I used earlier and it works! Unfortunately logging in normally still doesn't work. However, upon the desktop loading, I was greeted with 2 possibly related error windows:

Window 1 header: DigitalPersona Pro5.x Agent Window: DPAgent.exe - Bad Image

Window 1 body: C:\Windows\system32\SAMCLI.DLL is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.

Window 2 header: DigitalPersona Pro5.x Agent Window: DPAgent.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Window 2 body: The procedure entry point SAMCLI.NetUserGetInfo could not be located in the dynamic link library NETAPI32.dll.

How do I fix this login issue when trying to boot windows normally?

Comment: Back up important data then Run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say do an `sfc /scannow` and start disabling Startup items. If you can boot into safe mode it suggest some piece of rogue software/service is locking things up before the login completes.

Comment: I ran the command window as an administrator and ran your command from the C:\Windows\System32 directory. At 24% it gave me an error saying windows resource protection could not provide the requested operation.